# GNU Octave print_usage usage

Tags: octave

If I define this function in a file

```
function retval = my_fact (N)
    if nargin ~= 1
        print_usage ()
    endif
    retval = factorial (N)
endfunction
```

and call it from an interactive session, I get

```
>> my_fact ()
error: print_usage: 'my_fact' not found
```

My question is: Where should I write a "docstring" for factorial or the string I want octave to display?

Comment: Why don't you have a look at an arbitrary .m file in GNU Octave? For example http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/file/5e0350f5e2dd/scripts/image/bone.m Remember that GNU Octave is free software and encourages you to read and understand its sourcecode

Comment: @Andy Thanks a lot for the example. All I needed.